# Can you setup a on-premises artifact repository as a upstream source for Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure, devops, nexus, artifacts

We are going to start building in azure devops and we want to use Azure Artefacts as an artifact repository. However the Azure Artifacts will need to pull some dependencies that are located on a on-premise Nexus artifact repository. Is there a way to setup the on-premises Nexus as a upstream source for Azure Artifacts? From what I have read you cannot create a VPN to Azure Devops directly but only via custom build agents on VMs but that won't solve the Azure Artifact repository problem.